# Duplicate data when append data into file in python

Tags: python, loops, error-handling

I'm doing a python scripting for error handling where if i = j then data create new result but if i != j it saves the error data into a file.However, as the error handling is in the looping function (for i in data / for j in types), the error data saved in a file is duplicated for many times as showed in the result below.

Code:

```
with open(INPUT_PATH) as z:
    data = json.load(z)
    for i in data:
        if i['family']:
            if i['type']:
                for j in types:
                    if i['type'] == j:  
                        with morpfw.request_factory(setting) as request:
                            col=request.get_collection("data")
                            
                            item = col.create({"name":i["family"],"type":i["type"]})
                    
                    else:
                        with open('report.log', 'a') as l:
                            l.write(datetime +  i['name'] + "," + i['family'] + "," + i['type'] + "- invalid type")
        else:
            with open('report.log', 'a') as l:
                l.write(datetime  + i['name'] + "," + "," + i['type'] + "- No family name")
```

result (try to copy this result into a file to see the duplicate pattern):

```
16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)Downloader.Wowick16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)Trojan.W32.Vigorf16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)Trojan.W32.Vigorf16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)Trojan.W32.Vigorf16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)Trojan.W32.Vigorf16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)Trojan.W32.Vigorf16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)Trojan.W32.Vigorf16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)Trojan.W32.Vigorf16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)Trojan.W32.Vigorf16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)Downloader.Zirchap16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)test-malware16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)test-malware16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)test-malware16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)test-malware16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)test-malware16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)test-malware16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)test-malware16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)test-malware16-Dec-2020 (04:42:14.687834)test-malware16-Dec-2020
```

How should i fix the error handling so it will not duplicate the data?

Comment: Its even worse then callback hell, can you refactor if’s?

Comment: I’m sorry, but your code is not very sexy..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but with a small refactor and some modification this should be working if I understood your issue:

```
with open(INPUT_PATH) as z:
    data = json.load(z)

    for i in data:
        if not i.get("family"):
             with open('report.log', 'a') as l:
                l.write(datetime  + i['name'] + "," + "," + i['type'] + "- No family name")
            continue

        if i.get("type") in types:
            for j in types:
                if i['type'] == j:  
                    with morpfw.request_factory(setting) as request:
                        col=request.get_collection("data")
                        
                        item = col.create({"name":i["family"],"type":i["type"]})
            
        else:
            with open('report.log', 'a') as l:
                l.write(datetime +  i['name'] + "," + i['family'] + "," + i['type'] + "- invalid type")
```

As a side node, your code is [not so readable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) .

Comment: The 2nd else statement should be referred to the mapping function (if i['type'] == j). when I edit your code, the same error still happen where it duplicate the result.

Comment: If so I didn't understand your problem. If you check (if i['type'] == j) and than use the else to save the log if it doesn't match than you will have duplicated entries. For example, given
types = [a,b,c, d]
i[type] = c
With your code the if will be executed at most 1 time  (when j is a, b or d an entry log wil be created) and the else len(types)-1 times. With the proposed code you first check if the type of i is contained in types and if not you record 1 entry into the log.